# Sort an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have an iOS application witch have a search bar and a UITableView. when i click in the search bar for example "ta", the web services return to me all the words witch contain "at",
for example "beta","mota","at work","ebebebatbcbcb" , i would like to have just the words witch begin with "at", not all the words witch contain "at".

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will test all the solutions

Comment: "beta" and "mota" do not contain "at"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)array:(NSMutableArray *)array withstart:(NSString *)string{


NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",string];
[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
return array;
}
```

Or other way:

```
NSString *prefix = @"at";     
NSArray *final_array=[array objectsAtIndexes:[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                                              {
                                                  return [obj hasPrefix:prefix];
                                              }]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicate` is the way to go:

```
NSString *searchTerm = @"ta";
NSArray *matchingKeywords = [result filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@",searchTerm]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple answer

```
NSString *prefix = @"at";     
[array objectsAtIndexes:[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [string hasPrefix:prefix];        
}]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for [NSPredicate!](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)